# View Controller Management in IOS

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I need help with my control viewers in Xcode. In my storyboard, I created a navigation view controller. In which I created one view controller as my root view and added several objects in it.

Now in the general way, I'm trying to Ctrl + drag Element onto my View Controller. It doesn't show any Blue line like it is supposed to so.

Also I wish I can get some explanation or tutorials describing the method of creating views and controllers and linking them.

Comment: Are you talking about working with IB? And your 2nd question: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1) is great tutorial to understand storyboards(single view for all the views in application)  and Segues (transition between views). Go through both parts.